# Centering components in Vue3 + Vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am having trouble with centering a component horizontally. As shown on screenshot below, the  that holds the card element with tabs is leaning towards left side instead of center:

[image]

The whole code looks like this:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Navigation></Navigation>
    <v-main>
      <!-- Your main content goes here -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from './components/NavigationBase.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    Navigation
  }
}
</script>
```

RegisterView.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-card>
            <v-tabs v-model="tab" bg-color="primary">
                <v-tab value="one">Item One</v-tab>
                <v-tab value="two">Item Two</v-tab>
                <v-tab value="three">Item Three</v-tab>
            </v-tabs>

            <v-card-text>
                <v-window v-model="tab">
                    <v-window-item value="one">
                        One
                    </v-window-item>

                    <v-window-item value="two">
                        Two
                    </v-window-item>

                    <v-window-item value="three">
                        Three
                    </v-window-item>
                </v-window>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</template>
  
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            tab: null,
            tabs: [
                // Define your tabs here
            ],
            // Your other data properties here
        };
    },
    methods: {
        validate() {
            // Your validation logic here
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

NavigationBase.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app class="custom-menubar">
    <v-toolbar-title>Test</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-btn v-if="!user" to="/login" text>Login</v-btn>
    <v-btn v-if="!user" to="/register" text>Register</v-btn>
    <v-btn v-if="user" @click="logout" text>Logout</v-btn>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    // Your setup logic
    const user = ref(/* your user data */);

    const logout = () => {
      // Your logout logic
    };

    return {
      user,
      logout,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.custom-menubar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  /* Adjust the z-index as needed to ensure it overlays other content properly */
}
</style>
```

I'm still new in Vuetify, but I assumed using v-container should've stretched and centered the content inside it automatically? What am I missing here?

EDIT: Upon further inspection, it seems like my whole app is divided into two columns.Why??

[image]

Comment: Consider adding a sandbox (or similar), so that people can help you debug your application. You can very easily create sandboxes from public github repositories (see this [medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/open-any-public-github-repo-in-codesandbox-in-3-seconds-6e6f1cc930a5))